# Started a django server from inside Pycharm, but now I cannot turn it off

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm new to Pycharm IDE. Previously have been using Atom editor and a shell.  I am working in Windows 7.

Tonight I created a small Django project in Pycharm.  I used the "`Tools:  Run manage.py task`" menu option.  Then I ran `runserver` from the terminal it opened.

This launched my server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, as expected.

But later I accidentally closed the `manage.py` window pane in pycharm ide.  The server continues to run.  Even after I closed Pycharm,  the server remains running.

How do I stop it?!?!  Embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

If you closed the terminal the server should stop running, to check use this command. If this command produces no output in the terminal, then your server is not running.

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8000
```

Now if you see that there's a process running, the last number is the process ID in that line of output. Then you can replace "PID" with that number in the command below and that will stop the process from running.

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First kill django server using

   sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9

   Whatever PORT you are using you can replace with 8000 with it.
2. Right click on project main directory(Having Setting.py) ->Mark
   directory as-> Source Root
3. Edit Configuration Working Directory: leave blank

And then click on run Button.

It worked for me. I am using linux system, Not sure for Windows but this should work for windows too.